# How to run bash scripts in sequence and in infinite loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do I run
/tmp/1.sh
/tmp/2.sh
/tmp/3.sh
/tmp/4.sh
and then loop back to run /tmp/1.sh again? preferably in an infinite loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop inside a `while true` loop.

```
while true; do
  for script in /tmp/{1..4}.sh; do
    "$script"
  done
done
```

You can use any command that succeeds without doing anything in place of `true` including `((1))`, `[[ x ]]`, `printf ''`, `eval`, `:`, though `true` is the most obvious.

You could also use the C-style:

```
for ((;;)) {
  for script in /tmp/{1..4}.sh; do
    "$script"
  done
}
```

`/tmp/{1..4}.sh` (non-standard syntax initially from zsh) is one way to represent the `/tmp/1.sh` `/tmp/2.sh` `/tmp/3.sh` `/tmp/4.sh` list. You can also use csh-style `/tmp/{1,2,3,4}.sh` or `/tmp/1.sh /tmp/2.sh /tmp/3.sh /tmp/4.sh`. You could also use globbing with `/tmp/*.sh` to expand to all non-hidden filenames in `/tmp` ending in `.sh` in lexical order, though in bash which doesn't have `zsh`'s `(N)` glob qualifier or `ksh93`'s `~(N)` operator, you'd want a `shopt -s nullglob` for that glob not to expand to a literal `/tmp/*.sh` when there's no match.

Comment: if the sequence is like 3,1,2,4 how to do this?

Comment: @GodofMoney `for script in /tmp/{3,1,2,4}.sh` or plain Bourne `for script in /tmp/3.sh /tmp/1.sh...`. `for a in values` is from the Bourne shell, `for ((;;))` from ksh93, `{a,b}` from csh, `{1..4}` from zsh, all features eventually copied by bash.

Comment: works like a charm. thanks

Comment: @GodofMoney you should accept the answer, that's the way to say *thank you*  in these sites :).

Comment: ok. just done that